# C++ Structure with pointers, assignment and comparison

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

In the following program,

//1 and //2 are NOT working, but //3 is working.

//4 and //5 are NOT working, but //6 is not working.

Question:

If address values are same in if condition, why comparison is giving following error:

> error: comparison between distinct pointer types 'Node*' and 'int*' lacks a cast*

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node  
{
    int data;
    Node *Next;
};

int main()
{
    Node *Node1=new Node;
    Node *Node2=new Node;

    Node1->data=11;
    Node1->Next=Node2;

    Node2->data=22;
    Node2->Next=NULL;

    /* 
    if(Node1->Next==&Node2->data) //1
        cout<<"Node1->Next==&Node2->data"<<endl; //2
    */        
        cout<<"Node1->Next="<<Node1->Next<<"  &Node2->data="<<&Node2->data<<endl;//3 

    /*    
    if(Node2==&Node2->data) //4
        cout<<"Node2==&Node2->data"<<endl; //5
    */   
        cout<<"Node2="<<Node2<<"   &Node2->data="<<&Node2->data<<endl; //6

    if(Node1->Next==Node2)  //7
        cout<<"Node1->Next==Node2"<<endl;  //8 

        cout<<"Node1->Next="<<Node1->Next<<"   Node2="<<Node2<<endl; //9
}
```

--

```
**Output:**
Node1->Next=0x7fb05c460e00  &Node2->data=0x7fb05c460e00
Node2=0x7fb05c460e00   &Node2->data=0x7fb05c460e00
Node1->Next==Node2
Node1->Next=0x7fb05c460e00   Node2=0x7fb05c460e00
```

Comment: `if(Node1->Next==&Node2->data)` What did you expect with this?

Comment: Why are you comparing `Node->Next` with `&Node->Data` ? One is a pointer to a `Node`, the other a pointer to an `int`. What exactly are you hoping to achieve with the comparison?

Comment: You are trying to compare something of type `Node *` (i.e. the `Next` field) with the address of an `int` (i.e. the address of the `data` field). That does not make sense. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Ohh I got it, you 're writing random comparisons: `if(Node1->Next==&Node2->data)`, `if(Node2==&Node2->data)`, etc.. until you find something that works. Well, that's not gonna happen.

Comment: Hi All,Currently I am not developing any application. Just I want to understand how structures with pointers works. If memory locations exactly same, why the comparison is failing in if statement?

Comment: "If memory locations exactly same" Why? How?

Comment: Hi Dim, if you see the output of //3 and //6 are giving same address output, but if comparison is failing. I want to understand reason for this...

Comment: A pointer is more than an address - it also has a type. Different types of things can have the same representation, but you can only compare things that are of the same type.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing different pointer types i.e `Node*` with `int` . You can achieve this by simply typecasting the if conditions as

```
if((int*)Node1->Next==(int*)&Node2->data) //1

//and

 if((int*)Node2==(int*)&Node2->data) //4
```

You are right that addresses are same but C++ by default impose a strict type checking thats why you need to cast. Though avoid if possible

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea though. You're comparing apples to oranges and cast both of them to be a banana so they can be compared...

Comment: It seems that OP wants to learn something about memory address and struct layout (maybe): the above code is the way to check that the address of some Node structure in memory is exactly the address of the first int data member of the structure. Very likely, in this case, the answer is yes, they have the same address. Now that we know that in this specific case the two addresses are the same... let's forget it and don't write any code that count on a such an assumption (that will surely break, e.g. as soon as someone add a virtual function to Node struct)

Comment: Darhuuk : No its not a comparison between apples and oranges. All pointers are of same size and its safe to typecast them with int * just to compare.  Though it is avoidable, but there is nothing wrong in it. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: As soon as virtual functions and base classes and other thingsget thrown in, the first item you list in the struct might not be first... as long as it's clear the specific circumstances this works in.

Comment: Doctorlove :  you are right but in I doubt a single link list will serve any purpose with having a virtual function :)  anyway this question was asked more for learning than doing and i hope it clear now

Comment: Hi Gupta, Is type checking not applicable non pointer types See, below code, #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 
    int i;
    float f;

    i=5;
    f=5;
    
    if(i==f)
    cout<<"i == f"<<endl;
}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to compare the addresses stored in the pointers, and don't care about the type of the pointers. But the pointer comparison doesn't work like that. If you compare two pointers, their types would have to be same.

`Node1->Next` is of type `Node*` and `&Node2->data` is of type `int*`. That's why the comparison is failing. But if the types were same, then the comparison would have evaluated to `true`.

If you want to do that, you'd have to cast them to same type, maybe to `void*`.

```
bool compareAddresses(void* ptr1, void* ptr2){
    return ptr1 == ptr2;
}
```

and you could write your condition like:

```
if (compareAddresses(Node1->Next, &Node2->data))
```

Here, the pointers are automatically casted to `void*`. Similarly:

```
if (compareAddresses(Node2, &Node2->data))
```

See [this code live on ideone](https://www.ideone.com/79L3nI).